# Is there a website or resource that list places in Europe where you can ride a steam locomotive?

Tags: trains, where-on-earth, nostalgia

I recently went in a train with a steam locomotive. It's fascinating the way they work. I was wondering if it's possible to ride in the locomotive itself. Maybe even "drive" it, heat the furnace, and learn more about how it works. That would be a big plus!

Comment: I can think of several in the UK alone! Such as [Swanage Railway - Drive a Train](http://www.swanagerailway.co.uk/drive-a-train) in Dorset is just one

Comment: I never thought this was so popular and with so many options. I changed the question to know of resources listing places.

Comment: Great question, to bad there is this recurring pedantic atmosphere now of closing good questions :(. Anyway. Wikipedia is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heritage_railways

Answer (score 8):

I know three places in Germany where this is possible:

- [Mansfelder Bergewerksbahn](http://www.iks.hs-merseburg.de/mansfeld/alf/)
- [Selfkantbahn](http://www.heinsberger-tourist-service.de/deutsch/arrangements/erlebnis/einmal-lokomotivfuehrer-sein/)
- [Sauschwänzlebahn](http://www.sauschwaenzlebahn.de/angebotsvielfalt/nonplusultraauf-der-lok.html)

The first two offer active participation, while the last one only allows standing in the locomotive.

I would guess that some other steam locomotive clubs would allow others to participate as well, if you ask.

Comment: The last one (which i can recommend from personal experience) has an [English version of the web site](http://en.sauschwaenzlebahn.de/offers/nonplusultraon-the-locomotive.html) as well. However, the English version misses the sentence that you should wear dark, old clothing due to the exposure to coal.

Comment: @neo There is this site for switzerland: http://www.railevent.ch/pages/en/default_en.php  Can you please add it to your list? I think it would be bad to create another answer with just this link ^^

Answer (score 3):

This website provides details of Scenic railways and heritage train rides in Europe.This might be helpful.
http://traintraveling.com/europe/tourist-train-rides/index.html#austria

Answer (score 3):

Russian Railways have steam locomotive trips. Schedule and programme varies, I'm yet to try it myself.

http://rzdtour.com/

Doesn't seem to have an English version.

Answer (score 3):

Many heritage railways in the UK offer such a service - a quick search for "Steam Locomotive Driing Experience" brings up loads.

There is also the Wolstyn experience [www.thewolsztynexperience.org](http://www.thewolsztynexperience.org) in Poland, which allows you to drive a steam locomotive in regular service.